# Wordpress plugin only works when logged in

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, plugins

I have created a plugin, which leverages wp_ajax_no_priv_action so as to allow access when logged out. But the plugin only pulls data into the dropdown boxes, when you are logged in.

What am I overlooking here?

```html
<?php

/**
 * Plugin Name: Gyms
 * Plugin URI: http://www.gyms.com
 * Description: This plugin performs dynamic region updates into select boxes in WordPress
 * Version: 1.0.0
 * Author: Me
 * Author Email: 
 * License: GPL2
 */
function getregions_scripts() {
  wp_enqueue_script(
    'getregions-script',
    plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . "assets/getregions.js",
    array('jquery'),
    '1.0',
    true
  );

  wp_localize_script(
    'getregions-script', // this needs to match the name of our enqueued script
    'gymRegions',      // the name of the object
    array('ajaxurl' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php')) // the property/value
  );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'getregions_scripts' );

add_action( 'wp_ajax_showcountries', 'showcountries_callback' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_no_priv_showcountries', 'showcountries_callback' );
function showcountries_callback() {
include_once("pdo_mysql.php");

pdo_connect("localhost","user","password");
pdo_select_db("wpdb");


$makeselection=$_POST["makeselection"];

if($makeselection=="getCountryList"){
        $showcountry = pdo_query("Select data from usertbl");

   if (!$showcountry) {
       $message  = 'Invalid query: ' . pdo_error() . "\n";
       $message .= 'Whole query: ' . $showcountry;
       die($message);
   }else{
       $html = "<option value=''>Select Country</option>";
       foreach($showcountry as $row){
          $html .= "<option value='{$row[meta_value]}'>{$row[COUNTRY_NAME]}</option>";
       }
       echo json_encode($html, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
   }
}
..........

wp_die();
}

function showcountries_frontend() {
$the_html = '
<form id="MyForm">
    <div style="float: left">
        <select id="CountryList" onchange="getCities()" style="width: 150px !important; min-width: 150px; max-width: 150px;"></select>
        <select id="CityList" onchange="getTowns()" style="width: 150px !important; min-width: 150px; max-width: 150px;"></select>
        <select id="TownList" style="width: 150px !important; min-width: 150px; max-width: 150px;"></select>
        <select id="CategoriesList" style="width: 170px !important; min-width: 170px; max-width: 170px;"></select>
    </div>
</form>';
return $the_html;
}
add_shortcode("sc_frontend", "showcountries_frontend");
?>
```

plugins/assets/getregions.js

```html
function initialize($) {
    feedData($);
    categoriesData($);
}

jQuery(document).ready(function ($) { initialize($); });

function feedData($) {
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        console.log("feedData is successfully hit.");
        var serialized = $('#MyForm').serialize();
        $.ajax({
            cache: false,
            type: "POST",
            async: false,
            url: gymRegions.ajaxurl,
            data:{action: "showcountries", makeselection: "getCountryList", serialized}, //In wordpress the action: value must match the name of the callback function in the php file. In this case, showcountries_callback. Otherwise 0 is returned in success:
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data, status, error) {
                //$('#CountryList').append(data);
                console.log(data);
                console.log(status);
                console.log(error);
            },
            error: function (data, status, error) {
                console.log(data);
                console.log(status);
                console.log(error);
            }
        });
    });
}

function categoriesData($){
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        console.log("categoriesData is successfully hit.");
        var serialized = $('#MyForm').serialize();
        $.ajax({
            cache: false,
            type: "POST",
            async: false,
            url: gymRegions.ajaxurl,
            data:{action: "showcountries", makeselection: "categoriesList", serialized},
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                //console.log(data);
                 $('#CategoriesList').append(data);
            },
            error: function (data, status, error) {
                console.log(data);
                console.log(status);
                console.log(error);
            }
        });
    });    
}

.......
```

The readout I am getting from debugging the success: portion of function feedData(), reads as follows:

```html
0

success

Object { readyState: 4, getResponseHeader: .ajax/w.getResponseHeader(), getAllResponseHeaders: .ajax/w.getAllResponseHeaders(), setRequestHeader: .ajax/w.setRequestHeader(), overrideMimeType: .ajax/w.overrideMimeType(), statusCode: .ajax/w.statusCode(), abort: .ajax/w.abort(), state: .Deferred/d.state(), always: .Deferred/d.always(), then: .Deferred/d.then(), 12 more… }
```

Comment: php is fine, you need to debug the js/ajax calling it.

Comment: @David I have added my javascript file above, but do not know what to look for in relation to this issue. What am I overlooking?

Comment: @David I have updated the output from debugging the success: portion of function feedData(),which indicates to me that action: "showcountries" is failing because function showcountries_callback() in my php file is not visible, correct? If so, how do I rectify this?

Comment: the console will be your friend here, id be looking at console.log(gymRegions.ajaxurl) to see that is set correct first and then you need to double check your php functions are working, what is the output if you include the function on a page when not logged in?

Comment: @David console.log(gymRegions.ajaxurl) displays, "http://192.168.0.50/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php". Blank select (dropdown) boxes are output, when not logged in.

Comment: @David I think I misunderstood your last question, Were you suggesting that I add the js function(s) into my php file, and then see what the result of that is?

Comment: hmm, the 0 usually means that you are on the wrong file or the function is not found, try putting the php function in a page template and create a page for it, its going to be a case of var_dumps when logged in and when out to see whats wrong

Comment: @David I've solved the 0 issue. My action: was calling a function_callback that didn't exist. The issue I'm still having is that the plugin only works when logged in. I've read elsewhere that other plugins may be the cause of this issue, so I'll try disabling other plugins, and see how I get on with that.